# Power BI Embedded - Get current filters with Javascript

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have a working app based on the App Owns Data documentation & Javascript sample:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers

https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#

I am able to get the data out of each visualisation but I also want to know what filters are affecting it.

I can get the slicer states, but cannot get any filters applied by clicking on the charts. If you click on one datapoint, that filters the entire page. In the dashboard I can then click on the filter icon next to each chart and see 'Filters and slicers affecting this visual'.

I would really like to get this information via the JS API, but can't find it in the page.getFilters(), report.getFilters() or visual.getFilters().

Is it possible to do, and how?

Comment: Try to take a look at information returned when you capture a bookmark ([BookmarksManager.capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerbi/powerbi-client/bookmarksmanager.bookmarksmanager#capture_ICaptureBookmarkOptions_)). I've never tried to parse it, but it could be useful for you.

Comment: That gives me a state which is an encoded string. I see no way to translate that into something I can work with.

Answer (score 2):

For getting the filters applied on the visual, you can use the following:

```js
async function get_visual_filters() {
  // Get all the pages of the report
  const pages = await report.getPages();

  // Find required page
  const page = pages.find((p) => p.name === "ReportSection1"); // The page in which visual is present

  // Get the required visual.
  const visuals = await page.getVisuals();

  // Find the visual using Guid
  const visual = visuals.find((v) => v.name === "VisualContainer1");

  // Retrieve the filter of visual:VisualContainer1
  const filters = await visual.getFilters();
  console.log("The filters applied on the visual are: ", filters);
}
```

To get the page level filters, you can use:

```js
const pageFilters = await page.getFilters();
```

To get the report level filters, you can use:

```js
const reportFilters = await report.getFilters();
```

Output:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5q6d.png

Please refer following links:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/get-visuals
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters#get-filters

Comment: Thanks for this. However, the visual.getFilters does not get filters applied by clicking on other visuals